# Node.js pass values from one api to another

Tags: node.js

I need to get the value of "data":3 from  API1 and check in API2 if the field "data" has value greater than or equal to 3. I need to create a new API with API2 fields alone passing the filter criteria, please check the desired Json:

Json :

```
[
{
    "fieldid": "0001",
    "data": 3 , ---- API 1
     "field7": "2018-12-06T11:49:52.389Z" 
},
[
    {

        "field1": "E004",
          "data": 3, --- api 2
        "field7": "2018-12-06T11:49:52.389Z"
    },
    {

        "field1": "E005",
         "data": 2, ---- api 2
        "field7": "2018-12-06T11:49:52.389Z"
    }
],
```

]

Function :

```
n getlistofStaffs(req, callback) {
log.info(path.basename(module.filename), "List Staffs :: getlistofStaffs()");
var listofStaffsAPI = api url;

const requestOptions = {
    url: listofStaffsAPI,
    json: true
};

request(requestOptions, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        return callback(true, null);
    } else if (res.statusCode == 200) {

        var clearancesstaff=body[0].clearanceLevel;
        var staffClearanceId = body[0].staffClearanceId;

        return callback(null, {staffClearanceId:body[0].staffClearanceId,clearancesstaff:body[0].clearanceLevel});
    }
});
```

}

Desired Output JSON :

```
  [ {
    "fieldid": "0001",
    "data": 3 , 
     "field7": "2018-12-06T11:49:52.389Z" 
}
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Please find the functions:

Comment: Your code doesn't look anything like what's in the JSON you're posting. You've also only posted one function, and didn't indicate what problem you were having after trying the suggestions in my answer.

Comment: Is there is way I can mail you my code?

Comment: no, but you can post all the relevant parts here, and provide a link to a github repository or codepen or similar.

Comment: I added the file to GIT https://github.com/posridha/asyncwater

Comment: You haven't changed the getListofEvents function to expect the data from the getListofStaffs function, as described below.  Note the signature change in my code where I take 3 params instead of 2.  If you're binding the req object, then async will supply the second and third arguments ('fieldname' and 'callback' in my example).  The second param will be the same as the second param in your first function's callback (in your case the object that includes the clearanceId and clearanceLevel)

Comment: Paul thank you so much fr your advice, would you be able to give me snippet pls of my code?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?  I updated my answer with an update of your second function to include the additional parameter, but you weren't doing anything with it so i'm not sure what else you're looking for.

Comment: Oh Im sorry for not being clear...my whole confusion is with async.waterfall and passing the parameter...if you can write the sample with my actual code that will help me

Comment: I did, it's in the latest version of my answer, at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you...I updated my code on GIT...Looks like Im not getting any response from API....this was working fine...also I need to pass the Clearanceleev field in first api...Could you pls check if it is fine

Comment: Ok, first off clear up the code, right now you have several repeated functions with the same name.  Second, you're calling getListofStaff first, but according to your method signature it needs the clearance level of the staff, which you're not providing it in your waterfall.  If you do need it in the first place, pass it just like you're passing the request object.

Comment: Thanks Paul..fixed it and it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the async library, you'll want to make use of the `.waterfall()` method, which passes the callback data from one callback to the input of the next function.  Since I'm not entirely sure what your existing functions do, I'll demonstrate the signature I think is necessary to what you're trying to do, but leave the details up to you.

```
function getListofStaffs(req, callback) {}

function getListofEvents(req, fieldname, callback) {}
// later
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  async.waterfall([
    getListofStaffs.bind(null, req),
    getListofEvents.bind(null, req)
  ], (err, results) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    return res.send(results);
  });
}
```

If you're able to do it, it may be slightly more easy to follow your code if you're able to use the async/await features available in the last few versions of node.  If you can, then you'll just make sure your API calls return Promises, and then you can do this:

```
async function getListofStaffs(req) {}
async function getListofEvents(req, fieldname) {}

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const fieldname = await getListofStaffs(req);
    const events = await getListofEvents(req, fieldname);
    res.send({ fieldname, events });
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
}
```

There's also the [asynchandler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler) module you can use if you don't want try..catch blocks in your routes.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in my comment, you need to update your getListofEvents function to expect three parameters, based on your current design:

```
function getlistofEvents(req, clearanceData, callback) {
    var dt = dateTime.create();
    var formatted = dt.format('Y-m-d');
    console.log(formatted);
    console.log(clearanceData);
    log.info(path.basename(module.filename), "List Events :: getlistofEvents()");
    var listofEventsAPI = www.gmail.com;


    const requestOptions = {
        url: listofEventsAPI,
        json: true
    };


    request(requestOptions, function (err, res, result) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(true, null);
        } else if (res.statusCode == 200) {

            return callback(null, result);
        }
    });
}
```

Of course, your example code doesn't actually use that data, so I added a console.log to show it's there.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I am having problem in passing that value to the 2nd api...the following is the json response :

Comment: @posridha it's better to add additional information to your question, such as what responses look like, etc.  I would also recommend posting the code for your API fetching functions (e.g. getListofStaffs) as they are now.  It's very difficult to give you good advice w/o all the info.

Comment: @posridha again, put this information in your question please.  It's very difficult to read it in comments.

Comment: Updated the query with the Json and functions